# Modify an array of dictionaries, to add an element in each

Tags: javascript

How could I add an additional key value pair to each element in the following array.

```
get_project_list.completed = [{"user":"xyz","email":"a@123.com"}]
for (var i in get_project_list.completed) {
    i['status'] = "completed";
}
```

O/P `[{"user":"xyz","email":"a@123.com","status":"completed"}]`

There should be a simple solution to this but couldn't find one which worked.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `for in` loop for arrays, because it iterates over every enumerable property.

For example here I add to the array a new property, which is enumerable and in the `for in` loop I get it also.

```js
var arr = [{"user":"xyz","email":"a@123.com"}];
Object.defineProperty(arr, 'custom',  { value: 'myCustom', enumerable: true });

for(let prop in arr){
  console.log(prop);
}
```

If you are using **ES6** you can do via

**1)** [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function

```js
var arr = [{"user":"xyz","email":"a@123.com"}];

arr.forEach(item => item['status'] = 'completed');

console.log(arr);
```

**2) [for of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)** loop

```js
var arr = [{"user":"xyz","email":"a@123.com"}];
   
for(let item of arr){
   item['status'] = 'completed';
}

console.log(arr);
```

With **ES5**, you can use simple `for loop`

```js
var arr = [{"user":"xyz","email":"a@123.com"}];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   arr[i]['status'] = 'completed'; // get the current index-th item
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the index in the for loop and need to use it together with the array.

```
get_project_list.completed[i]['status'] = "completed";
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```js
var get_project_list = { completed: [{"user":"xyz","email":"a@123.com"}] },
    i;
    
for (i in get_project_list.completed) {
    get_project_list.completed[i]['status'] = "completed";
}
    
console.log(get_project_list);
```

For arrays, I suggest to use a for loop with a counter, because you get all enumerable properties and the order is not guaranteed.

```js
var get_project_list = { completed: [{"user":"xyz","email":"a@123.com"}] },
    i;
    
for (i = 0; i <get_project_list.completed.length; i++) {
    get_project_list.completed[i]['status'] = "completed";
}
    
console.log(get_project_list);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're transpiling (e.g. with Babel), I'd suggest using a `map` function in combination with the object spread operator instead.

```
let newList = get_project_list.completed.map(i => 
   {... i, status : "completed" }
)
```

This way, you don't have to mutate the old array.